# Why the new versions of PhpStorm don't appear as they should? (in Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

I'm not able to use any version of PhpStorm newer than 8 in Ubuntu.

Here's a screenshot of PhpStorm 8, looking perfectly:

[image]

And for example here's from PhpStorm 11 EAP:

[image]

As you can see, all the text (in the menus, notifications etc.) is so much bigger and the text in the editor is not clear.

P.S. I'm using Oracle JDK, but I think I had the same problem with OpenJDK as well.

```
$ which java javac 
  /usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/bin/java 
  /usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/bin/javac
```

Comment: Possibly it cannot detect your screen DPI settings correctly. You can override font settings at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behaviour | Appearance`. Also -- it's worth checking what Java is actually used by PhpStorm from `About` screen as from v11 it should be coming bundled with custom/own Java.